# Issue with python __eq__ method in checking if 2 lists are equal

Tags: python

I have a python program in which I have a class called Vector and an empty list inside of that class which is being populated runtime.
Here is the **init**:

```
def __init__(self,n):
    self.vector = [];
    self.n = n;
    for x in range(n):
        self.vector.append(False);
```

And here is the **eq**:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    t = True
    for x in range(self.n):
        if self.vector[x] != other.vector[x]:
            t = False;
    return t
```

however, when I try to check if 2 objects of this type are equal, I always get true, even though I changed values inside of vector in Vector class.
Here is the code where I do the above:

```
vectors = []
    n = tmp.size();
    k = calculateCombinationCount(n,int(n/2))
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(0,n-1):
            if (tmp.vector[j] != tmp.vector[j+1]):  
                t = True
                for x in vectors:
                    if x == tmp:
                        t = False;
                if t:
                    vectors.append(tmp)
                    tmp.printVector();
                tmp.swap(j,j+1);
```

I would appreciate any help that you can provide. Thank you :)

EDIT:

```
def swap(self,i,j):
    tmp = self.vector[i]
    self.vector[i] = self.vector[j]
    self.vector[j] = tmp

def calculateCombinationCount(n,r):
k = factorial(n)/(factorial(int(r))*factorial(int(n-r)))
return int(k)
```

Comment: Any chance `self.n` is zero?

Comment: No, I checked that with printing it.

Comment: I think the issue is in __eq__ because without it, it populates the list. The problem is supposedly in comparing 2 lists. I think it compares object references not the actual values inside. Do you think this can be the issue?
The thing is that I checked the documentation, and 2 lists are equal if the values inside are equal.

Comment: Can't you just do `return self.vector == other.vector`?

Comment: I tried that one as well. It doesn't work.

Comment: why don't you use `cmp()` method to check equality

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo probably because `cmp` does not exist in modern python.

Comment: @FHTMitchell yeah you are right. It depends on version

Comment: @LevonAsatryan `self.vector == other.vector` will always work. It is guaranteed by the language. You also don't need semi colons in python. Ever. There must be a problem in your logic. The final code block you've given us is also broken. `vectors = []` and `n = tmp.size()` are indented differently, which will cause an indentation error. I suggest fixing the code you've given us (and show us what `tmp` is) if you want help!

Comment: tmp is an object of type Vector, and I don't have any indentation errors, because indentation may have changed when I copied my code here.

Comment: You can edit your post and fix it... On SO you are supposed to give minimal working examples. Your code does not work as is (since `tmp` is not defined and the indentation error). We are not going to do the work for you. Also can you give us the `swp()` code?

Comment: I'm not asking you to do work for me, if you don't wish to help you may as well just leave. I'm not here to complain with you.

Comment: I **do** want to help you :) but at the moment I can't because I don't have enough information. Basically I need to know how `calculateCombinationsCount` and `Vector.swp` work.

Comment: I can do that, I will edit the post so you can see it like a code.

Comment: Ok, so if `tmp.vector` is initialised to `[False, False, ..., False]` to start with, then `tmp.vector[j] != tmp.vector[j + 1]` is always going to be False so all the code below it is never going to execute. Is that the case?

Comment: The `__eq__` method depends crucially on `n` being correct. You don't need to store it (because it should always be equal to `len(vector)`). And if one vector is shorter than the other you may get the wrong answer because you are not testing that the two vectors are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Right so I've updated your code to be much more [pythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (I can tell you come from another language, Java?).

```
from math import factorial

class Vector:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.vector = [False] * size

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Same if self.size == other.size
        """
        assert self.size == other.size, (self.size, other.size)
        return self.vector == other.vector

    def print_vector(self):
        print(self.vector)

    def swap(self, i, j):
        """
        More efficient and pythonic
        """
        self.vector[i], self.vector[j] = self.vector[j], self.vector[i]


def calculate_combination_count(n, r):
    """
    This is slow, I'd replace it with scipy.special.comb
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb
    """
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))


tmp = Vector(10)

vectors = []
n = tmp.size
k = calculate_combination_count(n, n // 2)
for i in range(k):
    for j in range(0, n-1):
        if tmp.vector[j] != tmp.vector[j + 1]:
            if not any(vec == tmp for vec in vectors):  # much more efficient
                vectors.append(tmp)
                tmp.print_vector()
            tmp.swap(j, j + 1)
        else:  # Just to prove why it doesn't work
            print('tmp.vector is all False: {}'.format(not all(tmp.vector)))
```

This prints out `tmp.vector is all False: True` repeatedly. I think this is your problem.

If you